# Converting date to worded date in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date in this format "MM/dd/yyyy".

```
string date = "03/30/2017"
```

I want to convert this string to this format- `Thursday, March 30, 2017`.

How can I do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Don't use string as a variable name :)

Comment: What about splitting the variable by `/` and then building a `DateTime` and use the desired format?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you seen [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I have tried to parse the date, but it didn't give name of day- like "thursday"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse string to `DateTime` object and then use [`DateTime.ToLongDateString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get string in required format:

```
var str = "03/30/2017";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var formatted = date.ToLongDateString();
```

Note that formatted string is culture sensitive. For *en-US* culture formatted string will be exactly in format which you want:

```
"Thursday, March 30, 2017"
```

You can also specify exact format manually, just as with parsing part:

```
var formatted = date.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy");
```

Check [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for reference.

Comment: ToLongDateString doesn't include the day name, or the commas.

Comment: @stuartd it does for `en-US` culture. Check [standard "D" format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy well I never. In `en-UK` it returns `30 March 2017`. Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should parse it by using

```
string date = "03/30/2017";
DateTime datetime = DateTime.Parse(date);
string nameddate = datetime.ToString("dddd,MMMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Other format options are found at
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx